# Use string value as if/else expression

Tags: php

This is probably *the* dumbest question out there and the answer is probably NO, but...

Is it possible to use the value of a string in the expression of an if statement? For example, say I pass

```
'if strcasecmp("hello", "Hello") == 0'
```

to a function and call it $string, could I then use that value as the conditional evaluation of an if statement?

```
if (the value of $string) {}
```

I know eval() will execute a string as if it was PHP code, but actually executes it and returns null/false, rather than just allowing the PHP surrounding the string to deal with the contents of string.  I also know you can use variable variables by using ${$varname} that will tell php to use the value of $varname as the name of a a variable.

So I guess what I'm looking for is kind of like 'variable code' instead of 'variable variables'.

Comment: Warnings about using eval aside, it is probably returning NULL because you have an error in your string. Does `eval('strcasecmp("hello", "Hello") == 0');` return the 'right' answer?

Answer (score 6):

I must guess a bit, maybe you want to `return` from `eval`?

```
 if (eval('return strcasecmp("hello", "Hello") == 0;')) {}
```

Also, there are closures that might add a bit more fluidity:

```
$if = function($string) {
    return eval(sprintf('return (%s);', $string));
}

$string = 'strcasecmp("hello", "Hello") == 0';
if ($if($string)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement does not return anything, so your example won't work. However, you can store the expression as a string and eval it later:

```
$expr = 'strcasecmp("hello", "Hello") == 0';
$val = eval($expr);
```

Now, keep in mind that using `eval` is extremely discouraged, as it can lead to serious security problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( eval("return ({$string});") ):
...
endif;
```

Though what you're trying to do is very bad.